# Dynamic SQL PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic, plpgsql

I want to know the basics of dynamic sql especially in PostgreSQL. I was googling for a while but have no luck for getting a good described examples. Maybe someone here could give me some links to the materials from which you where studying this subject.

Ok so to be more accurate I am interested in examples of especially PL/SQL (PostgreSQL) code which will demonstrate examples with description :)

Comment: Can you be a little less vague? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am not trying to do anything yet I want to learn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good place to start: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT

Look in particular at section called "Executing Dynamic Commands".

Comment: Thx I will look at it, any other materials?

Comment: so correct me if I am wrong: Dynamic SQL are simply commands executed via pl/sql sript code? In link provided above there are not many simple examples :)